# PIL's image.paste operation degrades image / drawn text quality

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am developing on a Windows 7 platform with Python 2.7.3 and PIL 1.1.7.

I am trying to write a python script to generate a set of images with text on them. Since I need to wrap text and fit it in an arbitrary bounding box, I wrote a method that draws text onto a white RGBA background image with the alpha transparency layer turned on. In order to simplify the problem, I wrote a small python script that illustrates the problem:

```
import Image,ImageDraw,ImageFont
import webbrowser

# sample text and font
text = "The text quality will degrade with the paste operation."
verdana_font = ImageFont.truetype("verdana.ttf", 20)

# get the line size
text_width, text_height = verdana_font.getsize(text)

# create a blank canvas with extra space between lines
blank_canvas = Image.new('RGB', (text_width + 10, text_height * 10 + 5 * 10), (255, 255, 255))

# create a blank RGBA canvas for the drawn text
text_canvas = Image.new('RGBA', (text_width, text_height), (255, 255, 255, 0))

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(text_canvas)

# draw the text onto the text canvas  
draw.text((0,0), text, font = verdana_font, fill = "#000000")

# print 10 lines
for x in range(0,10):

    # calculate the coordinates for the paste operation and debug 
    coordinates = (5, 5 + (x * (5 + text_height)))
    print "x = %d | coordinates = %r" % (x, coordinates)

    # paste the text onto the blank canvas
    blank_canvas.paste(text_canvas, coordinates, text_canvas)

    # create a temporary canvas
    temp_canvas = Image.new('RGBA', (text_width, text_height), (0, 0, 0, 0)) 

    # paste the text canvas onto the temp canvas using the png alpha layer for transparency
    temp_canvas.paste(text_canvas, (0,0), text_canvas)

    # swap the canvases
    text_canvas = temp_canvas

# save the blank canvas to a file
blank_canvas.save("paste-degradation.png", "PNG")

# open the image up to see the paste operation's image degradation
webbrowser.open("paste-degradation.png")
```

Each time the text gets pasted onto a new "temporary" canvas, the image quality of the drawn text gets worse and worse. The code above produces an image that looks like this:

[image: Degraded Text Quality]

Am I having an issue with my code? or is there a bug in PIL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that draw.text() has a slightly unexpected behavior.

draw.text() draws the text by setting some pixels to `fill` (the ones definitely inside the text), and not touching other pixels (the ones definitely outside).  However, if a pixel is found to be, say, at 25% part of the text, then draw.text() will simply set the new pixel to be 25% of `fill` and 75% of the old value.  But such ratios are applied to all 4 components of RGBA independently.  In this example, your background is (255, 255, 255, 0) and `fill` is (0, 0, 0, 255): so the 25%-in-the-text pixel will be (192, 192, 192, 64).

But I would argue that this is not the intuitive result.  The intuitive result would have been (0, 0, 0, 64).  If you paste such a text on, say, a fully red image, then the pixel above would still end up contributing 25% of the light gray color (192, 192, 192).  In other words you will see gray borders, where you'd expect only black, red, and colors inbetween.

(In fact the explanation above is too simplified: setting the background to (0, 0, 0, 0) does not help.  I suspect it is because that color is in fact equivalent to (255, 255, 255, 0), i.e. fully transparent.  Moreover it seems that the same algorithm is used in a `canvas.paste(img, (0,0), img)` call.)

A way to fix it is to only use the alpha band of images drawn from text, i.e. replacing `temp_canvas.paste(text_canvas, (0,0), text_canvas)` with `temp_canvas.paste("#000000", (0,0), text_canvas)`.

Comment: The suggested fix does work. Basically we're just using the alpha layer as a mask, and anything that isn't white on the "text_canvas" gets some shade of black (#000000) applied with a transparency alpha value. Is the quirkiness of the paste algorithm documented anywhere?